# is this the right way of "inverting" a byte? (bitwise NOT )

Tags: c

I have some code for display that seems to work fine. 
but when try to invert some of the text in the display (make white pixels black and black pixels white) I get an issue. the display acts up and crashes.

I have narrowed down the error to this inversion I do (maybe not correct word to descibe it?). When I remove it it works fine.

I think I am doing this correctly and I don´t know why this would be the issue but seems to be...
I do inversion like this:  (basically  bitwise NOT I guess its called)

```
variabel=~variabel;
```

(is this correct?!)

so what I am trying to do here is just make the ascii letters be the oposite: 
so for example:

```
11001000 will be:
00110111
```

or

```
10101111 would be:
01010000
```

FYI:
I am programing in C. Atmel studio. 
atmega 4809, SSD1305z display, SPI-simular interface

Comment: Perhaps you are inverting the control data as well as the display data?

Comment: That's the correct way to invert the bits in a byte -- but what data are you inverting? Inverting the representation of an ASCII character doesn't give you anything meaningful; `char c = 'A'; c = ~c;` will probably give you garbage. If you're inverting the bits in a chunk of memory that controls what pixels are displayed on a graphic display, you'll need to know just how the graphic image is represented in memory.

Comment: ASCII code units are not pixel bit images. They are integers. The type of inversion you describe does not apply. From a quick look at the SSD1305z datasheet, I think you have to supply your own character code to pixel map. You invert that output. (And, of course, you needn't use ASCII. ☺☻)

Comment: You need to specifiy what you mean by "make the ascii letters be the oposite".

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise NOT (`~`) (also known as Unary One's Complement) is the correct way to invert all bits of a value.

You can also invert bits by doing exclusive OR (`^`) with a value which contains `1`s in the bit position you'd like to invert.  This is particularly useful if you want to invert only a portion of the bits.